# Pull more than 250 mA from powerbank-powered Teensy 3.6

Tags: current, teensy

I'm using a powerbank speced 5V at 2.4A to power my Teensy 3.6 via the USB port. However, Teensy recommends to not pull more than 250 mA from its 3.3V pin.

Is there any way I can pull more current, at either 3.3V or 5V, without splicing the USB cable? I will use it to control WS2812(b?) LEDs.

Comment: you can use the Teensy to control the LEDs ... but you cannot use the Teensy to power the LEDs

Comment: That makes sense, thank you @jsotola. Do you have any suggestion on how to power the LEDs from the powerbank that I'm powering the Teensy with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Teensy 3.6 breaks out the USB input power on the VUSB pin (labeled on on the back).

This is the raw 5V in from the USB connector before it feeds the 3.3V voltage regulator.

See the schematics at the bottom of [this page](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy36.html#tech)

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that pin!